# IONIC 4 - How to release apk for Android 4.1.x (API level 16)?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4

IONIC 4 - How to release `apk` for `Android 4.1.x (API level 16)`?

I've already tried with crosswalk, but it does not working in `Ionic 4`.
And I've tried to release with the following command -

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release –- -- --minSdkVersion=16
```

It's OK to install, but I can't open it. Only show white screen.

Comment: And what is it doing when your are launching your app in a android phone with recent firmware ?

Comment: Showing white screen only. And do nothing